# Best practice to handle large form in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

There is a large form in my application. What is the best practice to retrieve data from that form and send to the API in Angular 5 ?

Comment: Use **`Reactive Forms`** : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you already have working code, this question might be better placed in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ with an example of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Best practices are :

- Separate your form in a component
- Using ngForm to build your form

That's pretty easy

Comment: It would be helpful for the user if you can explain your answer a bit more :)

Comment: It's coming soon, but I need to drink coffee right now :)

Comment: I am using reactive form to build the form. There are more than 90 fields. I got a post API from backend developers. All the form data I need to send to that API. So what I am doing is that first I am building whole the form and then again I am forming post request in submit function of that form. Is it I am doing right or some other way I can use ?

Comment: So your problem is not technical but in UX Design

Comment: No @Pterrat it's technical. I want to know what is technically correct? Building form first and then again forming data for request or there are some other way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a reactive dynamic form builder like the examples here.

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

https://stackblitz.com/angular/relgkgnvgxp

https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms

As far as submission you can either fire `onChange` or with an `onSubmit` function attached to the `<form>` element. Then simply add a button of `type="submit"` within the form.

This will give you the most robust usage of angular validation. I would also recommend exporting the form into a stand alone component. You can even use an event emitter to pass the form values to the parent component and handle the actual post request there for more reusability.