# Angular 7 ,Reactive Form slow response when has large data

Tags: angular, performance, angular-reactive-forms

I have a very complex and large data and I have to build a Reactive form around it in a component.

I've developed the form. But when I type something in one of the `input` fields to edit the populated data, it responds extremely slowly in updating the value of that field.

I tried using `updateOn:'blur'` and `'submit'` but without any luck.

My question is, what is best practice to handle the form with large data?

**Update**: This is my [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1yvsen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

**Note**: I've created a very minimal version of my actual implementation and I have performance issues in the Reactive Form.

Comment: [Related / Possible dubplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859056/best-practice-to-handle-large-form-in-angular-2) - Although I don't like the answer to this question

Comment: That would really depend on how you've created the form and how you're binding to it in your template. Please consider creating a Sample StackBlitz replicating the issue and sharing it here. It would be really helpful.

Comment: "i try to use updateOn:'blur' and 'submit' it". Sorry, I don't see that

Comment: @Eliseo  i try to use in my project but  it does not work so , i wll remove it

Comment: @SiddAjmera thank you ,i will update later

Comment: edited @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So after about a day of playing around with your StackBlitz, here I am with the solution. I think this would significantly improve the performance.

### Step 1: Create interfaces for your Data Model

Doing that would significantly make the code cleaner and more readable. It would also make the code more manageable and easy to work with. So here we go with the list of `interface`s for your specific scenario:

```
export interface Hotel {
  id: string;
  currencyId: string;
  hotelYearId: string;
  priceTaxTypeId: string;
  code: string;
  name: string;
  createBy: string;
  createDate: string;
  lastUpdateBy: string;
  lastUpdateDate: string;
  remark: string;
  internalRemark: string;
  roomTypes: RoomType[];
}

export interface RoomType {
  chk: boolean;
  roomTypeId: string;
  mealTypes: MealType[];
}

export interface MealType {
  chk: boolean;
  mealTypeId: string;
  marketGroups: MarketGroup[];
}

export interface MarketGroup {
  chk: boolean;
  markets: Market[];
  rateSegments: RateSegment[];
}

export interface Market {
  marketId: string;
}

export interface RateSegment {
  chk: boolean;
  rateSegmentId: string;
  hotelSeasons: HotelSeason[];
}

export interface HotelSeason {
  chk: boolean;
  hotelSeasonId: string;
  rates: Rate[];
}

export interface Rate {
  rateCodeId: string;
  cancellationPolicyId: string;
  dayFlag: string;
  singlePrice: string;
  doublePrice: string;
  xbedPrice: string;
  xbedChildPrice: string;
  bfPrice: string;
  bfChildPrice: string;
  unitMonth: string;
  unitDay: string;
  minStay: number;
}
```

### Step 2: Change the way you're creating the form

The way you're creating the form is extremely noisy. There's a clear way of doing that. And since you're already creating the form in the service, I suggest you keep the task of creating the form to the service itself and keep your component free from any such task. So your service can be refactored like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Hotel, RoomType, MealType, MarketGroup, Market, RateSegment, HotelSeason, Rate } from './hotel.model';

@Injectable()
export class UtilService {

  constructor(
    private readonly fb: FormBuilder,
    private readonly http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getHotelForm() {
    return this.getHotel().pipe(
      map((apiResponse: any) => this.fb.group({
        id: [apiResponse.id, Validators.required],
        currencyId: [apiResponse.currencyId, Validators.required],
        hotelYearId: [apiResponse.hotelYearId, Validators.required],
        priceTaxTypeId: [apiResponse.priceTaxTypeId, Validators.required],
        code: [apiResponse.code, Validators.required],
        name: [apiResponse.name, Validators.required],
        createBy: [apiResponse.createBy, Validators.required],
        createDate: [apiResponse.createDate, Validators.required],
        lastUpdateBy: [apiResponse.lastUpdateBy, Validators.required],
        lastUpdateDate: [apiResponse.lastUpdateDate, Validators.required],
        remark: [apiResponse.remark, Validators.required],
        internalRemark: [apiResponse.internalRemark, Validators.required],
        roomTypes: this.fb.array(apiResponse.roomTypes.map(roomType => this.generateRoomTypeForm(roomType)))
      }))
    );
  }

  private getHotel() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/hotel.json');
  }

  private generateRoomTypeForm(roomType: RoomType) {

    const roomTypeForm = this.fb.group({
      chk: [roomType.chk, Validators.required],
      roomTypeId: [roomType.roomTypeId, Validators.required],
      mealTypes: this.fb.array(roomType.mealTypes.map(mealType => this.generateMealTypeForm(mealType)))
    });

    return roomTypeForm;
  }

  private generateMealTypeForm(mealType: MealType) {

    const mealTypeForm = this.fb.group({
      chk: [mealType.chk, Validators.required],
      mealTypeId: [mealType.mealTypeId, Validators.required],
      marketGroups: this.fb.array(mealType.marketGroups.map(marketGroup => this.generateMarketGroupForm(marketGroup)))
    });

    return mealTypeForm;
  }

  private generateMarketGroupForm(marketGroup: MarketGroup) {

    const marketGroupForm = this.fb.group({
      chk: [marketGroup.chk, Validators.required],
      markets: this.fb.array(marketGroup.markets.map(market => this.generateMarketForm(market))),
      rateSegments: this.fb.array(marketGroup.rateSegments.map(rateSegment => this.generateRateSegmentForm(rateSegment))),
    });

    return marketGroupForm;
  }

  private generateMarketForm(market: Market) {
    return this.fb.group({
      marketId: [market.marketId, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  private generateRateSegmentForm(rateSegment: RateSegment) {
    const rateSegmentForm = this.fb.group({
      chk: [rateSegment.chk, Validators.required],
      rateSegmentId: [rateSegment.rateSegmentId, Validators.required],
      hotelSeasons: this.fb.array(rateSegment.hotelSeasons.map(hotelSeason => this.generateHotelSeasonForm(hotelSeason)))
    });

    return rateSegmentForm;
  }

  private generateHotelSeasonForm(hotelSeason: HotelSeason) {

    const hotelSeasonForm = this.fb.group({
      chk: [hotelSeason.chk, Validators.required],
      hotelSeasonId: [hotelSeason.hotelSeasonId, Validators.required],
      rates: this.fb.array(hotelSeason.rates.map(rate => this.generateRateForm(rate)))
    });
    return hotelSeasonForm;
  }

  private generateRateForm(rate: Rate) {
    return this.fb.group({
      rateCodeId: [rate.rateCodeId, Validators.required],
      cancellationPolicyId: [rate.cancellationPolicyId, Validators.required],
      dayFlag: [rate.dayFlag, Validators.required],
      singlePrice: [rate.singlePrice, Validators.required],
      doublePrice: [rate.doublePrice, Validators.required],
      xbedPrice: [rate.xbedPrice, Validators.required],
      xbedChildPrice: [rate.xbedChildPrice, Validators.required],
      bfPrice: [rate.bfPrice, Validators.required],
      bfChildPrice: [rate.bfChildPrice, Validators.required],
      unitMonth: [rate.unitMonth, Validators.required],
      unitDay: [rate.unitDay, Validators.required],
      minStay: [rate.minStay, Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

### Step 3: Leverage the above service:

Do it to get the Form and get rid of the `methods` that would return to you the `FormArray`s in your template. That would make your Component very clean, clear and concise.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { UtilService } from '../app/util.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class AppComponent {
  
  form$: Observable<FormGroup> = this.util.getHotelForm();

  constructor(private readonly util: UtilService) {
  }

}
```

### Step 4: Refactor your Template:

And this one is **THE MOST IMPORTANT**. **NEVER** call getters or methods in deeply nested forms to get the `FormArray`s. Or rather, in normal forms or inside a data binding syntax in general. Because they will get called in every single change detection cycle and would kill your App's performance.

> Please refer to [**this lightning talk by Tanner Edwards from ng-conf 2018**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ZvpdRM1eQ&t=31s) to know more about it.

So, you can refactor your Component Template like this:

```
<form 
  *ngIf="form$ | async as form" 
  [formGroup]="form">
    <div 
    formArrayName="roomTypes">
        <div 
      *ngFor="let roomType of form.controls['roomTypes'].controls; let index = index" 
      [formGroupName]="index">
            {{index}}
            <div 
        formArrayName="mealTypes">
                <div 
          *ngFor="let mealType of roomType.controls['mealTypes'].controls; let mealtypeIndex = index"
          [formGroupName]="mealtypeIndex">
                    mealtype {{mealtypeIndex}}
                    <div 
            formArrayName="marketGroups">
                        <div 
              *ngFor="let marketGroup of mealType.controls['marketGroups'].controls; let marketGroupIndex = index" 
              [formGroupName]="marketGroupIndex">
                            marketGroupIndex {{marketGroupIndex}}
                            <div formArrayName="rateSegments">
                                <div 
                  *ngFor="let rateSegment of marketGroup.controls['rateSegments'].controls; let rateSegmentIndex = index"
                  [formGroupName]="rateSegmentIndex">
                                    rateSegmentIndex {{rateSegmentIndex}}
                                    <div formArrayName="hotelSeasons">
                                        <div 
                      class="fifth_border" 
                      *ngFor="let hotelseason of rateSegment.controls['hotelSeasons'].controls; let hotelseasonIndex = index"
                      [formGroupName]="hotelseasonIndex">
                                            hotelseasonIndex {{hotelseasonIndex}}
                                            <div formArrayName="rates">
                                                <div 
                          *ngFor="let rate of hotelseason.controls['rates'].controls; let rateIndex = index"
                          [formGroupName]="rateIndex">
                          <div style="display:flex;flex-flow;row">
                            <div>
                              <p>SGL</p>
                              <input class="input text_right" type="text" formControlName="singlePrice">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <p>DLB/TWN</p>
                              <input class="input text_right" type="text"  formControlName="doublePrice">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <p>EX-Adult</p>
                              <input class="input text_right" type="text"  formControlName="xbedPrice" >
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <p>EX-Child</p>
                              <input class="input text_right" type="text"  formControlName="xbedChildPrice">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <p>Adult BF</p>
                              <input class="input text_right" type="text"  formControlName="bfPrice">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <p>Child BF</p>
                              <input class="input text_right" type="text"  formControlName="bfChildPrice">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre> -->
</form>
```

### Step 5: Don't stop here

This is not the end. It's just the beginning. You can also abstract the Child Form(the `marketGroup` `FormGroup` inside the `marketGroups` `FormArray`) into a separate component. And then you can set it's `changeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`. This would give you an even better performance.

> Here's a **[StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-forms-generate-very-large-form-final)** that you can refer to, to have a look at that solution.

Doing all this would significantly improve the performance of the form.

I hope this helps. I'll try to update this answer if I find anything else to improve the performance beyond this limit.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-forms-generate-very-large-form?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

---

> Here's a [**Detailed Medium Article**](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-i-increased-the-performance-of-an-extremely-deeply-nested-angular-reactive-form-by-380-c1b18ea668db) about this that I wrote for [**AngularInDepth**](https://blog.angularindepth.com/@siddajmera).

---

### Difference in Performance

I just did a Performance Audit on your Implementation as well as mine for the same set of steps performed on the App.

#### Here's the summary with your implementation:

[image]

#### And here's the summary with the refactored implementation:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you expain whice one mean in your Preformance Audit ?

Comment: I've already written a detailed Medium article about this. I'll share it soon enough and update my answer once done. Meanwhile, you can have a look at the Draft [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-i-increased-the-performance-of-an-extremely-deeply-nested-angular-reactive-form-by-380-c1b18ea668db):

Comment: thank you , i just start follow you in Medium ,Plase tell me if you finish your blog i will share you blog , i think is useful to another

Comment: i forget to tell something , i refactor my code is some <div> to <ng-container> 


<ng-container formArrayname="yourName">
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of FormArray">

</ng-container>
</ng-container>

that help improve performance

Comment: I'm working with huge forms either and can suggest you using classes for generating FormGroups. It's very powerful and convenient thing

Comment: @SiddAjmera what could you suggest for those dealing with huge nested forms where the form reset is required? The question is about `FormArray`s. I see only two ways of dealing with them: create FormArray from scratch or using while make it empty and re-create it's child forms patching initial values to them.

Comment: @Sergey, can you help me out with your scenario by creating a sample stackblitz to work with?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I did my best https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzc7mc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  Please note that this is an over simplified form example for the sake of saving time, because the real one can take up to day or two (I don't want to expose the real code so I would need to process it :) )

Comment: @Sergey can we move this into a new question? I'd also be interested in an answer to this. `this.formGroup.reset();` does not set FormArrays back to original and this suggests complexity  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852183/angular-2-remove-all-items-from-a-formarray

Comment: What an answer! I'm impressed, @SiddAjmera. 