# How to stop angular change detection when writing on input field?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-changedetection

My angular application is lagging on `<input>` fields and specially on `<textarea>` ones. I used chrome dev tools to inspected what was happening and I found out the whole component tree is being refreshed on every character I type.

I started with template driven forms, moved to reactive forms, tried changing to "OnPush" change detection, `runOutsideAngular` (this one I'm not sure I took the best approach because I created the `formGroup` inside it), nothing seems to work.

Is there any way I can stop these changes when the focus is on input fields?

Thanks.

Comment: After reading numerous articles about angular performance and change detection I found [this one](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-i-increased-the-performance-of-an-extremely-deeply-nested-angular-reactive-form-by-380-c1b18ea668db) from @SiddAjmera that also [answered a related question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532104/angular-7-reactive-form-slow-response-when-has-large-data#answer-54568730). <br>
My particular issues was with method calls inside interpolations "{{...}}" on the template. <br>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a much deeper problem at hand.  If angular is chugging that much on a value change you probably have some sort of design flaw.  I would strip out the logic in your component and start from a bare bones form. You can then work in a few changes at a time to see which one's are causing the lag.

If you post some code I can check it out and update my answer.

Sorry if this isn't a great answer, but I don't have high enough rep to just post this in a comment.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I would like to focus more on the change detection being triggered on every key stroke on an input/textarea field. I know what tasks are being triggered that are delaying the input, I just don't see a reason why they should be triggered and would like to stop it.