# What can cause input lag when using formControlName on a textarea?

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a textarea which I use in a formGroup:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <textarea formControlName="area"></textarea>
</form>
```

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
public form: FormGroup;

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
  area: new FormControl(null)
  });
 }
}
```

This works functionally, but for some reason the textarea becomes very slow in Firefox, IE and Edge. It works fine in Chrome. If I remove the formControlName the textarea is fine again (but of course does not work).
With slow I mean input lag.

If I isolate this component and put only this on the page, it is fine. So somehting else on the same page must interfere with it, but I have no idea what. The page consists of multiple components but nothing too fancy or complicated.
Validation only occurs when submit is pushed (using `(submit)`).
The same problem occurs on different pages, but the severity differs.

What can have such an impact that the moment I put on the formControlName there is input lag? Is there a way too measure possible performance issues? I have little experience in this area.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm so sorry, I don't have enough rep to make comments but) The issue could be from anywhere, I recommend you go through [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54568730/7334839) and cross-check your code with it. Good luck!